# Preferred table structure

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a program that involves a lot of data and I'm wondering what the best table structure would be.

My idea is to save all statistics of a player in a database. The statistics, named `stat_type`, can change so that means that a new `stat_type` can be added at a certain point.

This structure was my first idea.

Columns: `int playerID, VARCHAR stat_type, DOUBLE stat_value`

An example row would be: `1, "kills", 15`

This structure was my second idea.

With this structure, it is possible that a new column gets added at a certain point. This structure would require less rows than the previous structure, but will have more columns in the end.

Columns: `int playerID, DOUBLE kills`

An example row would be: `1, 15`

Which of these structures would be better performance-wise?

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](//meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post.

Answer (score 0):

Option1 is the what you want. You can add any stats you want later without changing your db design or your application logic.

Option2 when you change the schema you have to test everything connected to that table still work after those change, big manteince nightmare.

example with option1: can add new stats without code change

```
data = getdata_from_db();
foreach item in data
{
  <th> item.stat_type </th>
}
```

example with option2: if add new stats need to update your code to include that stat

```
data = getdata_from_db();
<th> item.needKnowFieldName1 </th>
<th> item.needKnowFieldName2 </th>
<th> item.needKnowFieldName3 </th>
```

Comment: I don't understand why adding a new column would cause so many issues. Can you elaborate ?